# Text didn't display but when I save it's display

Tags: flutter

Everything works except when I open the page displaying my data, the 'title' field does not open.
However, when I am in my code that I save as is, the text is displayed.
I don't understand why it doesn't appear automatically and why I have to save without even modifying the file so that the title appears.

My code is the next one :

```
Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              height: 35,
              width: 220,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  titleField.text,
                  style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: kColorPurple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              )
              ),
```

I would like the text to be displayed naturally without the need to refresh my code.

I'm setuping the Textfield.text with it :

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final titleField = TextEditingController();
```

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    titleField.dispose();
}
```

```
updateToFirebase() {
    databaseReference
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('Project')
        .doc(titleField.text)
        .update({
      'tricotTitle': titleField.text,
}
```

Someone have the solution ?
Thanks you for taking time to answer and resolve it.

Comment: You need to save to run hot reload. It will build your UI and display the content.

Answer (score 0):

since you said that it appears when you save your code more times, than it's when hor reload is executed, from it, I can say that your state is not updated when you're calling the method which displays the `Text`, you need to use

```
SetState(() {})
```

to update the state so it shows the text you want without performing a hor reload on your editor

Comment: That's a quite good idea but how can I put a ```SetState``` on a ```Text()``` ?

Comment: no, since like I saw you're using titleField.text which from it, I am assuming you're using TextField, right ?

Comment: if so, then you need to set an onChanged property in the TextField, then put SetState(() {}) inside that onChanged method, it will update the state every time the TextField's value changes

Comment: if you struggled with it, just put a snippet of code for the TextField and I will fix it

Comment: Yes I use it but isn't a TextField, it is just a `Text()`
I want to display it but I don't want to give to the user the possibility to modify it

Comment: Not really..
I put my code if you want to see how I did it

Comment: great, congrats !

Comment: It didn't work, I still have to refresh to see the result on my screen... And that's even if it's a simple `TextArea()`

Comment: That's not a`TextArea()` that's a `Text()`, my bad